# Why control statements is not working in Oracle Apex?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Is there any way around to make control statements work in apex?

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE 
    v_num NUMBER := 12;
    v_word VARCHAR := 'hello';
BEGIN
    IF v_num < 10 THEN
        DBMS.OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('IF condition executed.');
    ELSIF v_word = 'hello' THEN
        DBMS.OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ELSIF condition executed.');
    ELSE v_word = 'world' THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ELSE condition executed.')
    END IF;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Outside the control statement.');   
END;
```

This is the error I received every time I use control statements:

[image]

Comment: `DBMS.OUTPUT` should be `DBMS_OUTPUT` and `VARCHAR` within the local variable definition should have a length such as `VARCHAR(50)` or `VARCHAR2(50)`

Comment: `set serveroutput on;` is a sqlplus command, not a SQL or PL/SQL command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many little things wrong with your code. Start with the smallest possible piece, check it works and then add code - best way to start writing code in any language.

*Issue 1:* `set serveroutput on` is not needed in sql workshop. The server output is enabled by default and cannot be toggled. Try the following code:

```
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line('hello');
END;
```

and observe it works.
Then run this code

```
set serveroutput on
```

and... notice that you get the same error you're reporting !

*Issue 2:* typos typos typos. Each commented line below causes an error

```
DECLARE 
    v_num NUMBER := 12;
    --for VARCHAR, you need to declare the precision
    --no error but datatype VARCHAR should NOT be used. Instead use VARCHAR2
    --v_word VARCHAR := 'hello';
    v_word VARCHAR2(100) := 'hello';
BEGIN
    IF v_num < 10 THEN
        -- typo: there is no "DBMS.OUTPUT"
        --DBMS.OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('IF condition executed.');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('IF condition executed.');
    ELSIF v_word = 'hello' THEN
        -- typo: there is no "DBMS.OUTPUT"
        --DBMS.OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ELSIF condition executed.');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ELSIF condition executed.');
    --No condition needed after the ELSE keyword.
    --ELSE v_word = 'world' THEN
    ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ELSE condition executed.');
    END IF;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Outside the control statement.');   
END;
```